# Parsing String into mysql Date

Tags: java, mysql

I have a graphical user interface which takes some user inputs, it takes the current date also. Then I need to store them in a database. Everything is fine but I cannot understand the way how should I parse the input string of date field to mysql date for inserting it into the database.

I have a code like this.

```
Date date = txtToday.getText();
```

I know this should be parsed in to a type which is compatible with `Data` data type.
This `Date` type is from `java.sql.Date`.
How can I overcome this issue.?

Comment: Do you want `date` to be inserted in mysql date column?

Comment: try using SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 2):

MySQL’s default DATE field format is: YYYY-MM-DD

Whereas in Java, the Date class’ (available in java.util package) default format is,dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

so use this:

```
    Date date = txtToday.getText();
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String mysqlDateString = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println("Java's Default Date Format: " + date);
    System.out.println("Mysql's Default Date Format: " + mysqlDateString);
```

Comment: Date date = txtToday.getText(); does not work

Comment: System.out.println("Java's Default Date Format: " + date);
did this line print the date?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date dob = null;
    dob = sdf.parse(txtToday.getText());
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dob.getTime());
    c1.setDOB(sqlDate); //use this sqlDate for inserting into Database
    } catch (ParseException e) {
          System.out.println("Parse exception,incorrect input in the textbox");
          e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

Comment: This is the right answer.  It's assumes txtToday.getText() is returning the string that the user entered, in the format "dd-MM-yyy".  You are apparently returning blank instead.  Please provide the calling and implementation code.

Comment: @user3892439 be clear with your requirements, I've assumed that txtToday is the textbox in which user is entering the date in dd-MM-yyyy format

Answer (score 0):

If this line of code works...

```
Date date = txtToday.getText();
```

Then just use the time to convert it to a sql Date...

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: no that does not work. I put that there to let all of u know what I am trying to do.I am taking the date from a Jtextfield.

Comment: If you don't have a Date object yet, then Sam Dunk's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35818258/642706) to a [duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35814706/642706).

## Using java.time

Use the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

No need to use `java.sql.Date`. That class is replaced by `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

JDBC drivers that comply with JDBC 4.2 can deal directly with java.time types by calling:

- [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)
  myPrepStmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
- [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-)
  LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class );

For presentation of the `LocalDate` to the user, generate a String for display in your user-interface. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

You can go the other direction as well, [parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) an input string to get a date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Trap for the exception thrown if the user’s input is faulty or unexpected.

```
try{ 
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
    myPrepStmt.setObject( … , ld ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … // Handle the error condition of faulty/unexpected input by user.
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).