# Java parse date from TextField with a different format

Tags: java, mysql, date, parsing, format

I'm facing some problems in Eclipse with dates. I'm showing a date in a TextField with the format

`dd/MM/yyyy`

and I need to get the text from this textfield and parse it as a date to insert it in my database into a column of type `DATE` I'm using MySQL and it accepts dates as

`yyyy-MM-dd`

I tried really many options, both with `LocalDate` or the older `Date`, but didn't find a solution. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: What type is the column in your database?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

Comment: have a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prior Java 8 approach

Firstly, after retrieving your string from your `TextField`, you should parse it to `java.util.Date`:

```
String text = textField.getText();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date textFieldAsDate = null;

try {
    textFieldAsDate = sdf.parse(text);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    // deal with ParseException
}
```

Afterwards, you can convert your `java.util.Date` into a `java.sql.Date`, to store it into your MySQL database, like this:

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(sdf.format(textFieldAsDate));
```

### Java 8 approach

As mentioned by @BasilBourque, the Java date and time mechanism was provided by java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, and java.util.TimeZone classes which are now [legacy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html).

Therefore, in order to accomplish using Java 8 what was previously mentioned, one can do the following:

```
String text = textField.getText();
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.time.LocalDate textFieldAsDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

Afterwards, in order to convert the `LocalDate` into a `java.sql.Date`, to store it into your MySQL database, it's possible to do the following:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(textFieldAsDate);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem :)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for your warning. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `SimpleDateFormat` class

Once you have extracted it from the TextField, you can use this:

```
String extractedDate = "dd/MM/yyyy" // Whatever date you've extracted
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(extractedDate);
String correctDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
System.out.println(correctDate); // "yyyy-MM-dd" for whatever date was extracted
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = df.parse("2016-03-05");
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The other Answers are correct but use outdated classes. The old date-time classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. They have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

Define a pattern by which to parse your input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
```

Parse the input string as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)  object, representing a date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "23/01/2016" , formatter );
```

Someday the JDBC drivers will be updated to work directly with the java.time types. But until then we must convert to the java.sql types for transferring data to/from the database.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

Then use a `PreparedStatement`, calling `setDate` and passing your sqlDate to write the value into the database.

To retrieve from the database, call `getDate`. Immediately convert to java.time by calling `java.sql.Date::toLocalDate`. Minimize your use of the java.sql types. Do your business logic in java.time.

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can skip the java.sql types and use the java.time types directly.

- [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)
  myPrepStmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate )
- [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-)
  LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class );

This Question is really a duplicate. Search Stack Overflow for many more examples.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).